# how to add header in jPlayer function in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers, jplayer, request-headers

I tried like by adding headers inside jPlayer, its not working

```
const httpHeader = { 'authorization' : '123445'};
if (audioUrl) {
 $(this).jPlayer('setMedia', {
  mp3: audioUrl,
  duration: parseInt(duration, 10),
  headers : new Headers(httpHeader)
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `setMedia` method does not have a headers property, so this code will not work as-is.

To set the headers for a jPlayer instance, you'll need to use the `jPlayer` method to set the headers for the player as a whole, rather than setting them for a specific media file. To do this, you can use the `option` method to set the headers property for the player, like this:

```
const httpHeader = { 'authorization' : '123445'};
$(this).jPlayer('option', 'headers', new Headers(httpHeader));
```

This will set the headers for the player instance, and they will be used for all media files that are loaded by the players.

Comment: ```
const httpHeader = { 'authorization12334' : '123445'};
if (audioUrl) {
  $(this).jPlayer('option', 'headers', new Headers(httpHeader));
   $(this).jPlayer('setMedia', {
          mp3: audioUrl,
          duration: parseInt(duration, 10),
     });
 }  
```
tried like this, not working, can you please say what's wrong.